# Quartz2D: How to draw an arc of a circle?

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

I would like to draw an arc of a circle like in this sketch:

[image: sketch]

The angle of the arc should be variable and it should be colored with a gradient (e.g. starting with red and going to green). How do you do this in Quartz2D?

Thanks for your answers!
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

I think [this page](http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2009/04/drawing-pie-charts.html) has the arc part, while [this part](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/AdvancedDrawing/AdvancedDrawing.html) handles drawing of gradients.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
I didn't find out how to draw the gradient along the arc. Now I am coloring the arc with changing colors over time.